# How to Iterate over model instance? django

Tags: python, django

I am trying iterate over a model instance.
I would like to get this:
title1
title2

What I actually get
title1
title1
title1
title1
title1
title1

What seems to be the problem?

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404,

from .models import Paper 

def detail(request, slug):
    paper = get_object_or_404(Paper, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'papers/detail.html', {'paper': paper})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class Paper(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)


    def __str__(self):
       return self.title

    def save_in(self):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)

        super(test, self).save()
```

detail.html

```
{% extends "master2.html"  %}

{% block h1 %}
    <div id="g">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h3>{{ paper.title }}</h3> 
                <br>
                <br>
                 <div class="col-xs-12 "><p>{{ paper.large_description }}</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block title  %} Detail {% endblock %}
```

nav.html

```
            {% for title in paper.title %}
                <a href="{% url 'detail' slug=paper.slug %}">{{ paper.title }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
```

master2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link href="/static/font.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/static/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/static/font-awesome.min.css "rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/static/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>        
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0" data-target="#theMenu"> 
        {% include "nav.html" %}           
        {% include "header2.html" %}
        {% block h1 %}{% endblock %}
    <script src="/static/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/main2.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: How can you iterate over a single thing? Your Paper object only has one title; why are you expecting multiple titles?

Comment: I am trying to get 2 elements from my db by title.

Comment: So why are you "iterating" over just one of them? You're making no sense.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
{% for title in paper.title %} <!-- Im assuming you already have a
                                    {% for paper in paper_list %} statement 
                                    because a "paper" variable is not even
                                    passed to the template, "paper_list" was
                                    passed to the template. -->

    <a href="{% url 'detail' slug=paper.slug %}">{{ paper.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

You are iterating over a CharField (paper.title is a CharField). And then for each letter in `paper.title`, you are display the title, which is why you only get title1 all the time. To iterate over all the Paper objects and then display the title of each paper object, do this:

```
{% for paper in paper_list %}
     <a href="{% url 'detail' slug=paper.slug %}">{{ paper.title }}</a>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: @Ivic If nothing happens then that means a `Paper` objects does not exist in your database yet. Did you create a `Paper` object yet? When you open up the python shell and do `>>>paper_list = Paper.objects.all()` `for i in paper_list: print(i)` what does it print? Edit: Also, take a look at the code I posted one more time. I edited the code a bit and you might be using the unedited version of my code. Try it again. Does it still not work?

Comment: Do you have time for chat?

Comment: @Ivic Sure, create the chat room. You can also just reply here and let me know what still isn't working.

Comment: I think I don't have reputation.

Comment: I made migrations. I can see Paper object in admin. I used yor new code, still the same.

Comment: @Ivic Your index view renders the template `index.html` but in your post, you showed us `file.html`. Use the code I posted and place it in `index.html` and it should work. As long as you're passing `Paper.objects.all()` to the correct template in a variable called `paper_list`, the code I posted should work.

Comment: I add new code. You can see. Thank you for you time.

Comment: @Ivic I just saw your update. I believe the situation is very different with your update. I suggest re-editing your post back to the original, checking off this answer (because it was the original answer to the question), and asking any additional questions in a new post. FYI though, your new updated post looks like it should work (except for `paper.large_description` part because the paper object does not have a `large_description' attribute. But I'd suggest asking a new question with this post.